# undefined reference to `std::__default_alloc_template<true, 0>::deallocate(void*, unsigned int)'

Tags: c++

During linking code on ubuntu I get following error
`undefined reference to 'std::__default_alloc_template<true, 0>::deallocate(void*, unsigned int)'`

I tried several g++ compilers but nothing changes. The reason I found in previous answers is wrong configuration if includes. Here are includes in the code:

```
#pragma warning(disable:4786)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <png.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ft2build.h>
#include <gd.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

using namespace std;

#ifndef WIN32
#define stricmp strcasecmp
#else
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#endif
```

Please help to fix those includes?

Comment: you are probably missing a header. or may be you are compiling with gcc and not g++.

Comment: Some remarks: prefer `<cstdio>` and `<cmath>` to `<stdio.h>` and `<math.h>` in C++, `#include FT_FREETYPE_H` is wrong, `#ifndef WIN32` is wrong: use `_WIN32` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your are probably compiling *and linking* with `gcc` instead of `g++`. For compilation, there's not much difference. GCC uses the file extension to guess the real language, but when linking, `g++`also pulls in the C++ Standard library, which is where allocators are usually defined.

Comment: Dear rubenvb, Thank you. I changed headers as you recommended in the comment and get tool linked!